# Is there a way to dynamically get a list of documents in a Jekyll collection

Tags: jekyll

I'm fairly new to Jekyll, and am currently trying to build a site to hold a bunch of pages containing course training material. I'm trying to use Jeykll collections to do this and have a site structure like this:

```
/
|
|_ "_course001"
    |
    |_ subdirs/subdocs
|_ "_course002"
    |
    |_ subdirs/subdocs
```

When rendering content for each course (setup as a collection) I would like a navbar to display the other  documents in the current course/collection only (i.e. not in other courses).

Using something like this works:

```
{% for each coursedoc in site.course001 %} 
   [Create anchors and text]
{% endfor %}
```

However I want to have the collection name by dynamically assigned during the site build rather than hardcoded. I've tried doing something like this:

```
{% for each coursedoc in {{ page.collection | prepend: "site." }} %} 
   [Create anchors and text]
{% endfor %}
```

But this does not work, I guess because `{{ page.collection | prepend: "site." }}` returns a string.

Anyone have some suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And I think I just answered my own question:

```
{% assign collection =  site.collections | where: "label", page.collection | first %}

{% for node in collection.docs %}
[Create anchors and text]
{% endfor %}
```